# Find the time taken to mow the circular meadow

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

There was a circular meadow with diameter 160 m. A labourer wanted to mow the grass of the meadow with a mower of width 20 m and working with a speed of 113.3 km/hr. In how many seconds did he finish mowing the meadow ?

---

Please let me know how to proceed in the question

**My attempt:-**

Let the length of the mower be x meters, therefore are of the cross section of mower would be 20*x

Since the complete meadow has to be mowed,

Area of field = Total area mowed by the mower

Let t be the time required in seconds by the mower to do the task

$π * (80)^2 = t * (20*x*113.3*\frac{1000}{60*60})$

I have 2 variables in here , how to eliminate one of them ?

[image]

Comment: The "length" of the mower is almost surely irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: Why will the length be irrelevant , the area mown will be length of blade * width of blade , right ?

Comment: The length of the *blade* is of course relevant. But the front-to-back measurement of the mower (its "length") is not. If you have mowed lawns you would know this.

Comment: Alright yes it should be length of blade instead but even if I switch x as length of blade there will still be 2 variables in the equation , how will I eliminate one of them ?

Comment: Also is width of mower = length of blade ?

Comment: Where did you get a mower which can go 113.3km/h (that is more than 70MILES/hour? And it works mowing in a circle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misinterpreted the problem.

The width of the blade is actually the oher side of the blade.
[image: the side you named lenght is the width and the width is the lenght]

The lenght is irrelevant,because only the edge of the blade is cutting the grass.

The speed of the mower is $113.3km/h$,so it cuts $113.3km/h*20m$ in one hour.
So:
$$\pi*(80m)^2=t*113.3km/h*20m$$
$$t=\pi*6400m^2÷113300m*3600s÷20m$$
$$t=32s$$
This is the only way I see of solving this.

There is also a mistake in your attempt,which we can use to prove my theory.
When you wrote
$$π∗(80)^2=t∗(20∗x∗113.3∗\frac{1000}{3600})$$
you didn't use the measurement quantities.Let's insert them now.
$$π∗(80m)^2=t∗(20m∗xm∗113.3m∗\frac{1000}{3600})$$
When you solve this equation,you get
$$t=32s÷xm$$
We all know time is not expressed in meters,so it's obvious there's one number too much and I think it's this $xm$.

I might be wrong,but I think that really just the edge side of the blade is relevant here.